# How to detect if someone is trying to access my website without a valid client-side certificate?

Tags: browser, webserver, client-server, openvpn

How can you detect if someone is trying to access my website without a valid client-side certificate? 
Let's say I am visiting a website on my local network which has a self-signed cert. -So your browser will warn you about the missing valid cert. Does the server know if I have a valid certificate?

Comment: Can you please tell us what web stack you are using?

Comment: It's an OpenVPN Access Server

Comment: Generally this sort of info is either in log files or may be recorded in a database. You may also need to increase the logging level to get more detail about why authentication failed.